# EXCEL VBA issue returning #VALUE! instead of false through pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm new to VBA programming and I've run into a weird issue.
So I have a pivot table with 3 types of rows ("users", "Full Name", "Permissions").

I wrote a program to look for a certain name `x` in the `PivotTable`, and once it's found the name it looks at the following "permissions" and returns "True" if they 'Have Permissions'. Now the case when it returns "True" works fine, but for some reason every time it fails instead of returning false like I thought it would it returns #VALUE!,  does anyone know why?

```
Public Function Dependency(x As String) As String

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf2Value As String
Dim pf3Value As String

pf2Value = "False"
pf3Value = "False"
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each rngRow In pt.RowRange        
    If pf2Value = "True" And rngRow.PivotField.Name = "Permissions" Then
        If rngRow.Value = "Has Permissions" Then
                pf3Value = "True"
        End If
    End If
    If pf2Value = "True" And pf3Value = "True" And rngRow.PivotField.Name <> "Permissions" Then Exit For
    If rngRow.PivotField.Name = "Full Name" And rngRow.Value = x Then
        pf2Value = "True"
    End If
    If rngRow.PivotField.Name = "Full Name" And rngRow.Value <> x Then
        pf2Value = "False"
    End If
Next rngRow
Dependency = pf3Value

End Function
```

If I do this it does return false:

```
Public Function Dependency(x As String) As String

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf2Value As String
Dim pf3Value As String

pf2Value = "False"
pf3Value = "False"
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each rngRow In pt.RowRange
Next rngRow
Dependency = pf3Value

End Function
```

the issue starts when I add this line:

```
Public Function Dependency(x As String) As String

Dim rngRow As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf2Value As String
Dim pf3Value As String

pf2Value = "False"
pf3Value = "False"
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each rngRow In pt.RowRange
    If pf2Value = "True" And rngRow.PivotField.Name = "Permissions" Then
    End If
Next rngRow
Dependency = pf3Value

End Function
```

Comment: when you say you are looking for the name `x`, you mean in the `PivotTable`'s field name `"Full Name"` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes!  x will be something like "John Doe"  and every row labelled Full Name has a value like "Jane Smith"  and I am comparing x with the Full Name value to find the right person.  I should add that these rows are all in one column

Comment: see my answer and code below

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

***Public Function Dependency* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Dependency(x As String) As String

Dim pt          As PivotTable
Dim ptNameFld   As PivotField
Dim ptPermFld   As PivotField
Dim C           As Range

' set the Pivto-Table object, modify "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' set the Pivot Field "Full Name"
Set ptNameFld = pt.PivotFields("Full Name")

' set the Pivot Field "Permissions"
Set ptPermFld = pt.PivotFields("Permissions")

' loop through all rows in "Full Name" data range
For Each C In ptNameFld.DataRange.Rows
    If C.Value2 Like x Then ' if the name matches "x"
        ' for DEBUG Only
        'Debug.Print ptPermFld.DataRange(C.Row - ptPermFld.LabelRange.Row)

        Dependency = ptPermFld.DataRange(C.Row - ptPermFld.LabelRange.Row) ' get the value of "Permission", of the same row
        Exit For
    End If
Next C

End Function
```

***Sub TestDependency* Code** (to test the Function)

```
Sub TestDependency()

MsgBox Dependency("John Doe")

End Sub
```